# Adding tab with selected false but tab set color of tabSelectedTextColor

Tags: android, selection, android-tablayout

I am adding tab with selected false. Also I not want default tab selected as TabLayout is providing. So I observed that tab set color of `tabSelectedTextColor`. does any one have idea about to prevent default `TabLayout` selected or handle tab color even if we set selected false.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs_sub"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/blue_dark"
            android:tabStripEnabled="false"
            app:tabBackground="@color/blue_dark"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/blue" />
```

I am adding 4-5 tab dynamically and set false for all so it will take `app:tabSelectedTextColor` for all tab instead of `app:tabTextColor`. After click of any tab it will set given color but it is not handle first time same

```
tabs_sub.addTab(tabs_sub.newTab().setText("TAB1").setTag(details), false);
```

Comment: Can you please post your java codes?

Comment: @FerdousAhamed Hi, I am adding tab in tabLayout which i mentioned so which java code you want? I just add with selected false tab nothing

Answer (score 0):

I have checked it and got my answer.
It is not working when you have set selected color in XML so give it programmatically then it is working perfectly.